# Can I go out of LA airport during a layover without a visa?

Tags: visas, air-travel, layovers, lax, venezuelan-citizens

I'm a Venezuelan citizen and am taking a long flight from Venezuela to Australia. I'm taking two connections and changing airplane two times; my schedule is: Venezuela-Mexico; Mexico-L.A., L.A-Sydney. In L.A. the layover is approximately seven  and a half hours long during the afternoon; I arrive at 2 and depart at 10 approximately. So I was thinking if it's possible to get out of the airport, and do some shopping or even going for dinner... I don't really know if I need a visa for this or which type should it be?
Also I don't have any idea if the airport offers some type of luggage lockers or a luggage facility?
From L.A. to Sydney I'm traveling by Qantas, in First Class. Is there anyone who knows if Qantas offers some type of luggage keeping service?

Sorry for the length I'll appreciate any info, or help. Thanks. I might sound like a newbie, but i don't even know if it's enough time for going downtown and then going back to airport...

I just don't want to expend 7 hours alone in the airport.

Comment: It depends on your citizenship which you have not disclosed. The luggage will usually be tagged to your final destination, so you would normally not have access to it in L.A.

Comment: You are asking multiple questions, the visa one has already been asked. And as said in comment above, your luggage will go through anyway. The only matter is probably whether there is time to go out of the airport. But if you are flying First class, I guess you have no troubles paying for a cab to go anywhere you want

Comment: Venezuela citizens must have a visa to transit the US. You can obtain either a B-1/B-2 (business or tourist) visa or a C-1 transit visa. On any of these visas, you are allowed to leave the airport.

Answer (score 4):

If you would normally need a visa to enter the United States (which Venezuelan citizens do), then you also need a visa to transit through a US airport. This is true whether or not you exit the airport during your layover - if the plane you are on touches down in the US, you will need a visa.

Comment: Preemptive comment: An unscheduled emergency landing at a US airport is a different story.

Comment: It should be said that if you _deplane_ in the US. If you are on a technical stop that doesn't have to leaving the aircraft, you don't need visas.